# How to set "character tx delay" in GNU screen? (Like in minicom)

Tags: text-processing, terminal, gnu-screen, serial-console, minicom

Minicom has this useful setting called "character tx delay":

[image: minicom screenshot]

Is there a setting like this for GNU screen, too?

Comment: screen has a `slowpaste` setting that only applies when pasting text. For shell scripts, `expect` has a `send_slow` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a `screen` expert, so there is probably a better solution, but this might be good enough for you. `slowpaste` only applies to the `paste` command, but it is possible to use `xsel` to copy the current X11 selection to a file, and then use screen's `readreg` command to read this file into a register. Finally, `paste` can paste a register's contents. The following in `~/.screenrc` worked for me:

```
defslowpaste 100
bindkey ^v exec sh -c 'xsel -o >/tmp/sel; screen -X eval "readreg p /tmp/sel" "paste p"'
```

Using `slowpaste` and a per-character delay in milliseconds does not seem to work in this startup file as there is no current window yet, but setting the default value with `defslowpaste` works well.

This binds the <kbd>control-v</kbd> key to a shell script of 2 commands. The first one runs `xsel -o` to get the X11 selection into a file `/tmp/sel`.  The second one invokes screen with 2 builtin commands:  `readreg` reads the file into register `p`, and  `paste` causes the characters to appear with a delay of 100msecs between them.

This uses the information from Stéphane Chazelas's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/656852/119298) about `exec` returning immediately, so you cannot use `eval` to chain it with other commands; the answer also explains how using the default `exec` "fdpat" of `...` you can now replace the `xsel` by a `cat`, for example, and read input from the user upto an end-of-file <kbd>control-D</kbd>.

Comment: I dont know how to read stdin to a register, but I'll continue with some experiments. The `eval` is needed because there are 3 commands. The `exec` is needed to run a program (not a builtin screen command), and the `sh` is needed to have the redirection work (`>file`).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is no general TX delay. However, for pasting text with the `paste` command, `screen` has a `slowpaste` setting:

> Command: slowpaste msec
>
> Command: defslowpaste msec
>
> (none)
>
> Define the speed text is inserted in the current window by the paste command. If the slowpaste value is nonzero text is written character by character. screen will pause for msec milliseconds after each write to allow the application to process the input. only use slowpaste if your underlying system exposes flow control problems while pasting large amounts of text. defslowpaste specifies the default for new windows.

Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html

You can add the following line to your `.screenrc` to obtain a "slowpaste mode" for input from stdin:

```
bindkey ^V exec ... sh -c 'cat >"$HOME/.screen-slowpaste.tmp" && screen -S "$STY" -X eval "slowpaste 1" "readreg p \"$HOME/.screen-slowpaste.tmp\"" "paste p"'
```

It works by registering a new key binding for <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> which uses `cat` to listen for input from stdin (send EOF via <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to finish) and saves it into a file called `$HOME/.screen-slowpaste.tmp`. Afterwards, the contents are read into a register with `readreg` and pasted. In this example, the delay has been set to 1 ms with `slowpaste 1`.

You could also skip the temporary file by saving the input as an environment variable with `SCREENSLOWPASTE="$(cat </dev/stdin)"` and copying it into the register with `register p "$SCREENSLOWPASTE"`. However, this variant is very limited in the amount of text you can paste and you'll run into "command too long" errors quickly.