# In GNU screen, how to read from stdin and save into a register?

Tags: text-processing, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, gnu-screen, stdin

I'm using GNU screen and I want to save input from stdin into a register to slowpaste it later. I tried a workaround with a temp file (which I can read into a register with `readreg` afterwards) and to use `cat`:

```
:eval "exec | sh -c 'cat >/tmp/screentempfile'"
```

However, if I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to send EOF to `cat`, it doesn't arrive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should rather be:

```
:exec ... sh -c 'cat > ~/.screen-paste'
```

You need stdin of `cat` to be coming from `screen`, hence the first `.`. The command shouldn't output anything, so the two other fds don't matter much, though it makes sense for them to go to `screen` as well, hence the two other `.`s.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, this is a working command to read from stdin and save the input into a register:

```
:exec ... sh -c 'cat >"$HOME/.screen-stdin.tmp" && screen -S "$STY" -X readreg p "$HOME/.screen-stdin.tmp"'
```

Comment: Or just `:exec ... zsh -c 'screen -X readreg p =(cat)'`